# downloading csv file using dojo xhrget

Tags: servlets, csv, dojo, get

i have a csv file in my local which i try to return as response using a servlet. i call this servlet using dojo, but it seems it doesnt want to download it. i have set the response headers to "Content-Disposition" and attachment; filename=myfile, but it doesn't allow the file save as dialog to appear.

i think i read somewhere that dojo doesn't allow the file save dialog box to appear.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a question of "Dojo not allowing" the save dialog to appear - you cannot do such a thing via XHR by nature.

If you want someone to be offered a download as attachment, you'll need to do so using a full page request (such as an iframe).

Perhaps `dojo.io.iframe` would be worth a look: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/io/iframe.html